# loading multiple images with one image loaded on canvas at a time using kinetic js

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

how to Load a set of images into the canvas using Kinetic.js and that too not all images at a time one images should be loaded at a time.If you click next image the image should be traversed.

Comment: Do you mean to load from server (only when next is clicked) or show the next image in place of the current one? 2 Different things and 2 different approaches

Comment: show the next image in place of the current one... first senario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing image (showing one in place of other) in KineticJS can be done in the following manner.

Lets say you have 2 images which are already uploaded to an array variables imgs[]. In case you are not sure how to load images before processing them, you can read it [here](http://aniruddhaloya.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-ensure-images-are-loaded-before.html)

Lets say:

```
var imgs = new Array(2);
imgs[0] = "images/image1.png";
imgs[1] = "images/image2.png";
```

And lets define your display area as follows:

```
    var dispArea = new Kinetic.Image(
    {

    image: imgs[0],
    // You may specify the initial x,y position coordinates inside or set them later. 
    // Similarly for width, height, etc.
    });
    dispArea.currIndex = 0; //This sets up the index of currently shown image
    displayLayer.add(dispArea); //Assuming your layer is named as displayLayer
```

So for your **next button's** *"onClick"* event you call the function *"changeImage"* defined as follows:

```
    function changeImage()
    {
    // Increment the index, make it zero if it goes over the total images
    dispArea.currIndex = (dispArea.currIndex + 1)%imgs.length;

    dispArea.setImage(imgs[dispArea.currIndex]);

    displayLayer.draw();
    }
```

Comment: I have another question for you in kinetic js. Can I?

Comment: Sure, put it in another question on StackOverflow and send me over the link :)
If the answer worked for you, you may want to accept it, will be of help to others who might look at your question

Comment: This is the link for new qus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891841/in-kinetic-js-issue-with-rotating-a-kinetic-group-i-e-an-image Please help me out in this tooooo.