# In kinetic.js Issue with rotating a kinetic.group

Tags: javascript, css, html, kineticjs

I am using kinetic js. I am adding image, lines, etc to a kinetic.group and trying to rotate the group and it is getting rotated correctly. But after rotating the group, if I try to draw a line it is not correctly drawing on the present mouse position. It is drawing as it was before rotating.

The problem may be that if I rotate the group, the stage co-ordinates are not getting rotated it seems. What should I do to prevent this?

reference code---

```
var rootGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
                    x:  stage.getWidth()/3, 
                    y:  stage.getWidth()/6, 
                    draggable: true,
                    offset: [images.darthVader.width/2, images.darthVader.height/2]
                });
rootGroup.add(line);
rootGroup.setRotationDeg(rootGroup.getRotationDeg()+90);
```

IN THIS WAY  I AM DRAWING THE LINE.

```
 var activeline = new Kinetic.Line({
   points: [{x:0,y:0}],
   stroke: "blue",
   strokeWidth: 3,
   lineCap: "round",
   lineJoin: "round",
 });
 var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();

 points.push({
            x: mousePos.x,
            y: mousePos.y
 });

 activeline.setPoints(points);
 rootGroup.add(activeline);
```

Comment: Is your line object a member of Kinetic.group? Can you paste some reference code?

Comment: ya absolutely line object is the member of the group. I will post some code for. var rootGroup = new Kinetic.Group(); rootGroup.add(line); rootGroup.setRotationDeg(rootGroup.getRotationDeg()+90);

Comment: Your code doesn't show where and how you are drawing the line. It seems that you are updating line coordinates after rotation, using coordinates returned from mouse position, which are relative to screen position and not the group. I think one possible way is to rotate the line (on its starting point) everytime you draw it.

Comment: I HAVE POSTED THE CODE REGARDING DRAWING A LINE please once have a glance on it and then reply with the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with KineticJS, but it seems that you have to reset the transformation matrix back to its default state. OpenGL has the glLoadIdentity() method. Search for a similiar method on KineticJS.

See this tutorial
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-reset-transform-tutorial/

Comment: ya It is but not completely.I have tried the same thing but has't worked

Answer (score 0):

This should get you fairly close: http://jsfiddle.net/k4qB8/24/

```
 // This rotates that added active line along with your group.
 // This makes the draw direction correct
 activeline.setRotationDeg(0-rootGroup.getRotationDeg());
```